# Change only some values in categorical column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Consider that I have `df` like this:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~Country, 
  "Bangladesh", 
  "India", 
  "Nigeria", 
  "China", 
  "France", 
  "Canada", 
)
```

and I only wanted to change some names not all. For instance, only China and France. I tried the below code but it repalces NA for the rest.

```
shortNames = c("China" = "CHN", "France" = "FR")
df$Country <- shortNames[df$Country]
```

Comment: Try running `shortNames["China"]` and then `shortNames["India"]` and see if you can work out what's going on.

Comment: `df$Country[match(names(shortNames), df$Country)] <- shortNames`

Comment: or: `i <- df$Country %in% names(shortNames); df$Country[i] <- shortNames[df$Country[i]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need exclude the names not in `shortNames`.

```
i <- df$Country %in% names(shortNames)
df$Country[i] <- shortNames[df$Country[i]]

df
#  Country   
#  <chr>     
#1 Bangladesh
#2 India     
#3 Nigeria   
#4 CHN       
#5 FR        
#6 Canada
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use `stringr::str_replace_all` which takes named vector to replace values.

```
df$Country <- stringr::str_replace_all(df$Country, shortNames)
df

# A tibble: 6 × 1
#  Country   
#  <chr>     
#1 Bangladesh
#2 India     
#3 Nigeria   
#4 CHN       
#5 FR        
#6 Canada
```

If you want to use it in `dplyr` pipes, you can do -

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% mutate(Country = str_replace_all(Country, shortNames))
```

Comment: Thanks. That is a very concise way to the problem. But for now I prefer the base R answer provided by @GKi.